# What's the fastest algorithm to perform exponentiation?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

What's the fastest algorithm to perform exponentiation? Let's assume natural number bases and exponents for simplicity's sake.

What would an efficient math library use?

(When I search for it, I just get results pertaining to algorithms that run in exponential time.)

Comment: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/12/10/fast-exponentiation/

Comment: I think this asked hundred time in SO.

Comment: What do you mean by "exponent of a number"?

Comment: Knuth has devoted several pages of [TAOCP](http://www-cs-staff.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html) Volume 2 in this problem.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with all of the binary methods above is that they are limited to integers only.  If by "exponentiation" you mean compute the e^x function, the best I have seen is power series that converge quickly, and polynomial, rational, or Pade approximations that are valid over a limited range.

One thing for sure: if you find a lightning fast algorithm for e^x to 96 decimal places, you will also have found a faster way to compute logs (by Newton-Raphson).  In fact, Newton-Raphson converges quadratically, so you double the number of digits of precision in your log with each iteration. This was a favorite of Nate Grossman of UCLA back in the Forth days.

Back in the days of four-banger calculators, I used to use e^x = (1+x/1024)^10.  Of course that breaks down for x very large or very small, but you can see why it works. If you have a square root button, you can reverse this idea to get logarithms.  But you don't need square root for the exponential function.

I wonder if there is some inversion of the AGM algorithm that could do the exponential function...  Hmmm....

Answer (score 2):

For small exponents Python uses binary exponentiation (a type of exponentiation by squaring) as can be seen at line 2874 of http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/longobject.c?view=markup&pathrev=65518

For larger exponents it uses a 2^5-ary exponentiation (an alternative type of exponentiation by squaring).

If you only care about the most significant digits of the result, then you can very quickly calculate x^y=exp(y*log(x)).

If you only care about the least significant digits of the result (e.g. for a programming contest), then you can calculate the exponent modulo some value M. For example, the Python command pow(x,y,1000) will compute the last 3 digits of x to the power of y.  It does this by the exponentiation by squaring method, but note that this can be much faster than computing the full result because it makes sure that the intermediate numbers are never larger than M.

As an additional twist (if you are only interested in the least signficant digits), you can use Euler's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem to reduce the size of the exponent.

Comment: That svn.python.org link isn't good anymore; I think this is the relevant code (now on GitHub) though: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4369

Answer (score 0):

If you have a given natural number u and a given input m, to compute u^m you could apply the following algorithm

```
q = m;
prod = 1;
current = u;
while q > 0 do
     if (q mod 2) = 1 then // detects the 1s in the binary expression of m
          prod = current * prod; // picks up the relevant power
          q--;
     endif
current = current * current; // u^i -> u^(2*i)
q = q div 2
enddo

output = prod;
```

So basically if you have, lets say, u^23
you convert 23 to binary -> 10111(base 2) 
Then you get u^23 = u^16 * u^4 * u^2 * u^1 (no u^8 since the 2 digit from left to right is 0)

The complexity is O(log(m)) or O(n) if you consider n to be log(m)_10 + 1

Comment: This analysis doesn't concerns the running time of multiplication.